# Remove first number from string Jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

I have string: `"  12.3  I love paris 1990"`.

String I want receive after remove first number is: `I love paris 1990`

Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you have static string or can be change number and string?

Comment: Using jQuery? +1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it using `regular expressions` as follows,

```js
$('#regxme').text(function(i, txt) {
  return txt.replace(/-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+/, '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="" id="regxme"> 12.3  I love paris 1990</a>
```

Comment: you should add explanation on the regex

Comment: Thank you so much. Let me check it.

Comment: Is it ok with int number only?

Comment: @MinhAnh yes. please accept if helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This is the best way for your requirement:

```js
var str = "  12.3  I love paris 1990";
str = $.trim(str)
str = str.substring(str.indexOf(' ')+1);
str = $.trim(str)
alert(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your solution is good and easy to understand but leaves whitespace at the beginning of the resulting string.

Comment: Correct @Flyer53....I missed that part...i just needed to trim one more time as you have done...i have made edit to my ans which removes whitespace...

Comment: @Flyer53 Thanks for suggestion...upvoting your answer.

Comment: Thanks, but you came up first with the basic idea. So it's only fair to give you a +1 as well.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to perform this task more than once in your script. So here is a function to do this.

```js
var string = "  12.3  I love paris 1990";

function removeNo(str) {
  let newstr = str.trim();
  return newstr.substring(newstr.indexOf(' ')+1).trim();
}

console.log(removeNo(string));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps :)

```
var str = "12.3  I love paris 1990";
    var res = str.split(" ");
var processedstr="";
for(var i=1;i<res.length;i++)
{
   processedstr += res[i];
}

console.log(processedstr);
```